# I can't find the problem with this error on angular

Tags: angular, angular13

I got this error on angular [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z4iO.png)

and this is my service :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r563Z.png)

and this is my function on the component.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzziL.png)

the problem is on the consol ther is a lot of error : ERROR TypeError: ctx.list is undefined
ConsltoppoComponent_Template consltoppo.component.html:

also whene the data is null the page is blocked, i have other service is working good.

on html i call the list like that : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdEjk.png)

and  the type of the list is **any**

i hope i explain the problem, to get help of this problem

Comment: don't post images. post code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an asynchronous call, that sets the result to the field `list`. As long as the call is pending `list` will be *undefined*, which will lead to errors, since you try to read `typ_pret` from `list`. It means you try to read a property of *undefined*. Make your template safe, add an `*ngIf="list"` to your input element.